# I am unable to execute a mapreduce job in a Hadoop cluster

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera-quickstart-vm

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.13.0.jar -file mapper.py -mapper mapper.py -file reducer.py -reducer reducer.py -input /user/cloudera/test.txt -output /user/cloudera/result
```

I am using this command to execute MapReduce program using Mapper as`mapper.py` and Reducer as `reducer.py`

It throws an  an error `Not a valid JAR:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.13.0.jar`

I am using MobaXterm and VMBox & My home directory is `/user/cloudera`, mapper program location `/user/cloudera/mapper.py`
reducer location `/user/cloudera/reducer.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `cloudera` distribution for practice, the `JAR` will not be available in the mentioned location `/usr/lib/hadoop` .
The hadoop-streaming JAR  will be present in `/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/`

Run with the updated location of the `JAR`, it should work fine.